# What constitutes comercial use of software?

Tags: software

I'm writing a module for the internal company website of my current employer. Does that constitute comercial use?

Comment: Not to sound rude, but how would that not be commercial use?

Comment: The idea is that what I am developing has no bearing at all on the comercial part of the company.

Comment: The company is making money somehow though.

Answer (score 1):

Commercial means "concerned with or engaged in commerce" and commerce means "the activity of buying and selling, especially on a large scale". So, if your employer is engaged in buying and selling (anything) then what you are proposing is commercial use.